# Issues with GQL query, Google Datastore. Error with multiple conditions and greater than and less than operators

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, gql, app-engine-flexible

I am trying to query the Datastore, and my query looks like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE Latitude = "18.1" AND Number > "1"
```

It doesn't work though. I get this error in the Datastore query box:

> GQL query error: Your Datastore does not have the composite index
>   (developer-supplied) required for this query.

And this error when I run my code:

> no matching index found. recommended index is:\n- kind:
>   mydb\n  properties:\n  - name: Location\n  - name:
>   Number\n

Simple requests like this work:

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE Number > "1" AND Number < "5"
```

I am only accessing a single column here maybe that is why?

Nope,

Then I tried a request like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM mydb
WHERE Latitude = "18.1" AND Number = "1"
```

This worked.

I tried to look up a solution, and I came across this page: https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/tools/indexconfig#Datastore_About_index_yaml

After going through that page, I gathered that I need an index.yaml file somewhere. It is supposed to go in a folder called WEB-INF. But I don't have this folder.

This is a little snippet of my code:

```
Query<Entity> query = Query
                .gqlQueryBuilder(Query.ResultType.ENTITY,
                        "SELECT * FROM " + kind + " WHERE Location = @location AND Number <= @number")
                .setBinding("number", "5").setBinding("location", "18.1").build();
QueryResults<Entity> results = datastore.run(query);
```

Comment: Where is your `appengine-web.xml` located?

Comment: @Nicholas I don't have it anywhere, my program can deploy and run without it.

Comment: Can you post the full directory structure of your application?

Comment: @Nicholas Sure, this is what my project is based on, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/java-docs-samples/tree/master/managed_vms/sparkjava

I don't have -- test/java/com/google/appengine/sparkdemo as I did not need it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error you get is because the query you're attempting requires [**Composite indexes**](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/indexes) which are not available by default.  They must be specified within `index.yaml`.

The article [Creating index files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml#creating_index_files) which is somewhat different than the one posted is specifically for Java applications running in the flexible environment.

There are 2 ways to create an `index.yaml`:

1. Manually using your favorite text editor following the rules and structure as prescribed in [Index definitions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml#index_definitions).
2. Generate the file as you test locally.  This can be done using the `gcloud beta emulators datastore start` command.  You can also use the `--data-dir <dir>` option to specify where the generated `index.yaml` should be written.

Then, once you have `index.yaml` and the same directory as `app.yaml`, you can deploy it with `gcloud preview app deploy index.yaml` from that directory.  This process is briefly documented in [Deploying the index file](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/configuring-datastore-indexes-with-index-yaml#deploying_the_index_file).

I would also recommend reading [Organizing yaml Configuration Files](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/yaml-configuration-files).

Comment: Thank you, I'll go ahead and try this, however there are two places that contain app.yaml files, one is in src/main/appengine and the other one is in  target/appengine-staging. Which directory should I put index.yaml in?

Comment: `src/main/appengine` as I assume where you are running `gcloud preview app deploy`

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Hello again, I was able to upload the index file, and I can see it on Datastore, however, I am getting the same error in the GQL query box.

Comment: It began working. Initially, I put in all the property names in index.yaml, but then I updated it and only added the properties that I needed to work with in the file and that got it to work. 

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it! :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues with this topic. Make sure that the properties you add on the `index.html` **are exactly the ones you need**. In my case, I was adding two numeric properties, as Datastore does not allow multiple inequality operators (greater than, etc) you can't query neither of both with that.

So I upload a new `index` with just one of them and it allow me to do the query.

Hope it helps in some way,

Cheers!